# rails 4 devise not matching password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am migrating rails 3.2 to rails 4 where I am facing issue of devise not able to authenticate my existing user have changed the rails 4 changes as below

```
 before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

    def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me) }
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) { |u| u.permit(:login, :username, :email, :password, :remember_me) }
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password) }
  end
```

In devise.rb

```
config.case_insensitive_keys = [ :email , :username ]
config.strip_whitespace_keys = [ :email , :username ]
```

devise 3.0.4,  bcrypt-ruby 3.1 and rails 4 while signing the below error I am facing

```
  Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"yEQsn0cRdMdHvh5HYFvLyjIoW7G85X+sujK0iHS73SQ=", "user"=>{"username"=>"tony_test", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 3ms
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"yEQsn0cRdMdHvh5HYFvLyjIoW7G85X+sujK0iHS73SQ=", "user"=>{"username"=>"tony_test", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}
```

Please let me know if any configuration I am missing.

Thank you

Jagdish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by adding this in devise.rb

`config.authentication_keys = [:username]`

Answer (score 0):

Change the `devise.rb`

devise.rb

```
config.case_insensitive_keys = [ :username ]
config.strip_whitespace_keys = [ :username ]
```